# Problems getting populate to work correctly

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to build a forum and have come across some problems when trying to add answers with information of the user to a specific post. I am able to list the answers for a single post in the frontend, however I am unable to populate the user information, as for now I only get an id. Here are my models and endpoints to post and get the answers. What am I missing?

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Username is required!'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true 
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required!'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (value) => {
        return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(value)
      },
      message: "Please enter a valid email address"
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is required!'],
    minlength: [8, 'Password must be a minimum of 8 characters!']
  }, 
  accessToken: {
    type: String, 
    default: () => crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex')
  }
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
  title: { 
    type: String, 
    required: [true, 'Field cannot be blank'],
    minlength: [2, 'Your post must be a minimum of 2 characters!'],
    maxlength: [50, 'Your post must be a maximum of 50 characters!']
  },
  post: {
    type: String, 
    required: [true, 'Field cannot be blank'],
    minlength: [2, 'Your post must be a minimum of 2 characters!'],
  },
  votes: {
    type: Number, 
    default: 0
  }, 
  createdAt: {
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now()
  },
  answers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Answer'
  }],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
 }
})

const Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', {
  answers: {
    type: String,
  },
  number: {
    type: Number, 
    default: 0
  }, 
  post: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now()
  }
})

app.get('/posts/:id/answers', authenticateUser, async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const newAnswer = await Post.findById(id).populate('user', 'username').populate('answers').exec()
  res.json({ success: true, newAnswer })
})


app.post('/posts/:id/answers', authenticateUser, async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const { _id } = req.user
  const { answers, post } = req.body

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(_id)
    // get answer and save post id
    const newAnswer = new Answer({
      answers: req.body.answers,
      post: id,
      user
    })
    // save answer
    const result = await newAnswer.save()
    // find post and push the comment into the array in the same moment
    const answeredPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
      $push: {
        answers: result 
      }
    }).populate('user', 'username').populate('answers').exec()
    res.json({ success: true, answeredPost})
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid request', error })
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you mean `user` as a property of `Post` document, or `user` as a property of `answers` subarray documents?

Comment: I mean user as a property of answers subarray document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Post.findById(id).populate('user', 'username').populate({ path : 'answers', populate : { path : 'user'}}).exec()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but it is still only showing the user id and not the username.

Comment: Can you add a response that you are getting to the question?

Comment: I had an error in my frontend, your solution worked, thank you! :)